# Docksal mysql issues

Tags: 9

I have a couple docker/docksal projects on my Macbook M1. Today, MySql issues prevent either from being used.

The one thing I did earlier was to install homebrew and the Pantheon terminus brew. But I did that to see if I could get a clone of the site working on my local… ie this problem already existed.

When I reboot, restart docker, do a fin start or up, the instances loads cleanly

```
[+] Running 4/4
 ⠿ Network wfw_default  Created                                            0.0s
 ⠿ Container wfw-db-1   Started                                            0.3s
 ⠿ Container wfw-cli-1  Started                                            0.3s
 ⠿ Container wfw-web-1  Started                                            0.9s
Connected vhost-proxy to "wfw_default" network.
Waiting for project stack to become ready...
Waiting for project stack to become ready...
Project URL: http://wfw.docksal
```

but when I attempt a fin sqlc, I get:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 192.168.64.1:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 192.168.64.1:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of HumbugBox3140\KevinGH\RequirementChecker\RequirementCollection::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush8/.box/src/RequirementCollection.php on line 14

Deprecated: Return type of HumbugBox3140\KevinGH\RequirementChecker\RequirementCollection::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush8/.box/src/RequirementCollection.php on line 14
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of HumbugBox3140\KevinGH\RequirementChecker\RequirementCollection::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush8/.box/src/RequirementCollection.php on line 19

Deprecated: Return type of HumbugBox3140\KevinGH\RequirementChecker\RequirementCollection::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush8/.box/src/RequirementCollection.php on line 19
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-3)
SQL client error occurred.                                           [error]
```

At first, one project (that was already up prior to rebooting) continued to work, but no longer does after restarting.

fin logs db produces the following, and attempting to hit the home page yields a 502

```
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.5+maria~focal started.
wfw-db-1  | Running init scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ as root...
wfw-db-1  | Including custom configuration from /var/www/.docksal/etc/mysql/my.cnf
wfw-db-1  | Running init scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ as root...
wfw-db-1  | Including custom configuration from /var/www/.docksal/etc/mysql/my.cnf
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.5+maria~focal started.
wfw-db-1  | Running init scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ as root...
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] mysqld (server 10.6.5-MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to guess base node address. Set it explicitly via wsrep_node_address.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to guess base node address. Set it explicitly via wsrep_node_address.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Warning] WSREP: Guessing address for incoming client connections failed. Try setting wsrep_node_incoming_address explicitly.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] WSREP: Node addr: 
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using ARMv8 crc32 + pmull instructions
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 268435456, chunk size = 134217728
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.5 started; log sequence number 3529016502; transaction id 1519135
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'definer' at position 3 to have type varchar(, found type char(93).
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH','EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL','SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_B
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 1 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
wfw-db-1  | Version: '10.6.5-MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
wfw-db-1  | 2022-06-18 15:42:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220618 15:42:18
```

Adding docker ps output:

```
    CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                      NAMES
233ced20aa35   docksal/mariadb:10.6-1.3   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   43 minutes ago      Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                                 wfw-db-1
79ff6eae495f   docksal/ssh-agent:1.3      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   45 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes (healthy)                                                docksal-ssh-agent
694c42fb2c11   docksal/dns:1.1            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   45 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:53->53/udp                         docksal-dns
9cd98480712f   docksal/vhost-proxy:1.7    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   45 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes (healthy)     0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   docksal-vhost-proxy
647826faaf84   docksal/apache:2.4-2.5     "httpd-foreground"       About an hour ago   Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                                 wfw-web-1
88e8713e9382   docksal/cli:php8.1-3.2     "/opt/startup.sh sup…"   About an hour ago   Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                                 wfw-cli-1
```

Comment: What does `docker ps` say?

Comment: Added output, above.

Comment: I don't think this is a Drupal problem. But if you want to use Docker with Drupal, I would suggest looking at DDev (https://ddev.readthedocs.io/), which handles all the docker stuff for you, leaving you to only need to do the Drupal stuff.

Comment: Is this mysql image compatible with arm64? This is an important distinction, you may need a newer tag of the images you are using. But this is not a Drupal specific issue. I'm also unsure if Pantheon is running Maria 10.6.2 yet, maybe it's incompatible with your docker version?

Comment: I can’t ignore that they’ve been running fine for weeks. Maybe it’s to do with ps reporting that the dns is unhealthy.not sure why. But ddev is worth a try if it removes these headaches (and because Jaypan is typically right). Just tried Lando. It timed out I think on the dns. Docksal didn’t time out though.

Comment: At the very lest, DDev is pretty easy to quickly migrate to and test with to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: @Jaypan Docksal is like DDEV.

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't realized that. I didn't see they have Drupal specific templates.

Comment: I tried reinstalling Docker and Docksal. Moving the question to stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672779/new-issue-on-previously-stable-docksal-implementations